# Can a variable be passed to Playwright JS config in global-setup.js file?

Tags: javascript, playwright

JS newbie here so please excuse any misconceptions I may have about JS or Playwright...

I have config.js file setup with projects and for each project I define custom variables (like login creds, etc.). How can I access these values in the `global-setup.js` file when I use the `--project=ProjectName` when I run the test?

I can use testInfo in tests to access these values, but can I access it in `global-setup.js`, since (as I understand it) is adds to the config object?

I am trying to use one global-setup file for login in with credentials from either one or another project, which are defined in the config.js file.

So I would run this:
`npx playwright test testFile.spec.js --project=FirstProject`

The `playwright.config.js` file would have this setup:

```
  {
    name: "FirstProject",
    username: "blahblah",
    password: "blahblah",
  },

  {
    name: "SecondProject",
    username: "blahblah1",
    password: "blahblah1",
  }
]
```

And in `global-setup.js` I would like to check which project is being used in order to provide the correct credentials -- something like this:

```
module.exports = async config => {
const username = config.projects[${projectName}].username;
const password = config.projects[${projectName}].password;
```

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The playwright documentation suggests you create a fixture. For instance, a file called **my-test.js** at the level of **playwright.config.js**:

```
// my-test.js
const base = require('@playwright/test');

exports.test = base.test.extend({
  // Define an option and provide a default value.
  // We can later override it in the config.
  person: [{username: 'john', password: 'john123'}, { option: true }],
});
```

Then inside **playwright.config.js**:

```
/**
 * @see https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration
 * @type {import('@playwright/test').PlaywrightTestConfig<{ person: { 
username: string; password: string } }>}
 */
const config = {
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'FirstProject',
      use: { person: {username: 'blahblah', password: 'blahblah'} },
    },
    {
      name: "SecondProject",
      use: { person: {username: 'blahblah1', password: 'blahblah1'} },
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally, you can use the fixture in the spec file:

```
// testFile.spec.js
const { test } = require('../my-test');
const { expect } = require('@playwright/test');

test('test 1', async ({ page, person }) => {
  await page.goto('https://example.com/');
  await page.fill('input[name="login"]', person.username);
  await page.fill('input[name="password"]', person.password);
});
```

In order to execute the test, use the cli:

```
npx playwright test testFile.spec.js --project=FirstProject
```

I tried the code and it worked for me. More information:

- Playwright docs: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parameterize#parameterized-projects
- https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration#projects